# How to write a batch script for IGV that directly leads me to my chosen BP range on each chromosome

Tags: bioinformatics, viewer, genome

as input for the script I have a list of BP ranges on several chromosomes and I am wondering how to write an IGV script that directly leads me only to these areas, without showing the whole chromosomes.

Thanks for your help in advance

Input:

Chr xy1 BP-start BP-end,

Chr xy1 BP2-start BP2-end,

Chr xy2 BP1-start BP1-end,

Chr xy2 BP2-start BP2-end,

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/9512067/

Comment: See instructions here: https://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/batch